# Setting max-parameters on Listeners for Domain Server (Wildfly 9)

Tags: xml, parameters, jboss, wildfly

I'm having some trouble with an application exhausting the default 1000 parameters listeners have, particularly https listeners. Unfortunately, the server that the application is setup on is running Wildfly 9 in domain mode, and most of the advice I've found for changing the max parameters on a Wildfly server refer to servers running in standalone mode.

I've got the following listeners setup in my domain.xml, but am still getting a "UT000047: The number of parameters exceeded the maximum of 1000" exception:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp" max-parameters="5000"/>
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" max-parameters="5000"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" max-parameters="5000"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"  max-parameters="5000"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="modcluster"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="My Server"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="MyHeader"/>
        <mod-cluster name="modcluster" management-socket-binding="http" advertise-socket-binding="modcluster"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp" max-parameters="5000"/>
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" max-parameters="5000"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="my.host.local">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

I've set the `max-parameters` argument on all the undertow listeners I could find out of desperation, but this is not working, so how should the max parameters actually be set in this sitation?

Comment: You know need to know what profile your server is running in. Then you could use CLI to update it.

Comment: Ok let's say I know the profile, what CLI commands would update the max-parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to determine the profile your server is running on. You can do this in CLI with something like:

```
/server-group=main-server-group:read-attribute(name=profile)
```

Once you have the profile, `full` in the default case, you can edit the attribute with the following CLI command:

```
/profile=full/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:write-attribute(name=max-parameters, value=5000)
```

Essentially it would be the same as what you find for standalone, but you prefix the path with `/profile=your_profile`.

Comment: No luck, the commands run successfully but the application still claims it has exceeded the maximum of 1000.

Comment: It requires a reload of the servers. Did you reload them after the change?

Comment: Restarted, not sure if its strictly required to reload rather than restart.

Comment: No a restart would in a sense do a reload. There must be a different setting you're looking for.